# How to increase/replace all numbers in a script

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++, textpad

I have a pretty large SQL script that has duplicate identities on the database the inserts are taking place on.

If I could increment all ints within the script by say 20 this should get round the issue. I was trying to suss out how to do this in Notepad++ and Textpad but failed miserably.

Was hoping someone may have some suggestions on how I could do this.

Comment: Can you add an example of before/after? Excel/Spreadsheet are often useful for this type of wrangling.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Can you post a few sample lines of your script?

Comment: Sorry guys, don't have it to hand right now. Can post tomorrow. However the script is just a load of INSERT INTO .... VALUES () I need to effectively just find every int within the values and increase it by n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what you are looking for. You could add a zero to the end of every integer with ease. Post an example and I might be able to help more. Notepad++ tricks are one of my favorites.

```
Enable Regex Searching in Notepad++. 
Search for   :([0-9]*[0-9])
Replace with :\10
( \1 is the value that was found )
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Will give it a go tomorrow. I don't have the script to hand but its essentially lots of the following: INSERT INTO tableName VALUES( 10203, 45 'fdsfs'. gdgdf', 54, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating your script, perhaps you can simply decrement your existing DB values by 20 (-20) to be able to run your script as-is.  Either way, you'll have to account for changing what might be primary and foreign keys -- and retaining those relationships.

Comment: Don't think thats going to be possible. Thanks for the input though.